# sending a data frame to a function; error result in min/max

Tags: r, function

I'm sending a dataframe into a function and my goal is to add another column named **S.COLOR** that holds the result of either RED/GREEN. This is done by checking if the year was profitable or not (profitable means the Adj. Close of the stock on on 31-Dec is bigger then Adj.Close on 1-Jan of the same year).

the (head) Data Frame looks like this:

```
  Date           Adj.Close   YEAR
1 2014-01-24     30.45       2014
2 2014-01-23     31.48       2014
3 2014-01-22     32.29       2014
4 2014-01-21     32.63       2014
5 2014-01-17     33.40       2014
6 2014-01-16     32.00       2014
```

.
.
.

and my function looks like this:

```
stock.color<-function(df)
{
  my.year<-df$YEAR

  #print(my.year) <--- this is OK it's a vector
  dfsub<-subset(df,YEAR==my.year)

  #print(dfsub) <--- this is OK it's a vector

  minDate<-min(dfsub$Date) #<---problem here everything is the same date 1993-01-01 
  maxDate<-max(dfsub$Date)

  print(minDate)

  s<-subset(dfsub, Date==minDate)
  e<-subset(dfsub, Date==maxDate)

  amount.s<-s[,c("Adj.Close")]
  amount.e<-e[,c("Adj.Close")]

  if (amount.e>amount.s)
    return ('GREEN')
  return ('RED')
}
```

sending function example:

```
stock.data<-transform(stock.data, S.COLOR=stock.color(stock.data))
```

The problem that I have is that the min/max function return the same discrete result and that is 1993-01-01 and 1993-31-12 so the end result of the new column is incorrect.

Question: Why do I get the same result on MIN/MAX and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The expression `YEAR==my.year` is `TRUE` for every value in `df`, so you're not subsetting at all. `transform` doesn't do "split-apply-combine" on it's own.  You need to use `plyr` or `data.table` or some such.  Here is untested `data.table` example:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(stock.data)
dt[
  order(Date), 
  S.COLOR:=if(head(Adj.Close, 1) < tail(Adj.Close, 1)) "GREEN" else "RED",
  by=YEAR
]
dt
```

and the `ddply` version:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(
  stock.data[order(stock.data$Date), ], 
  "YEAR", 
  transform, 
  S.COLOR=if(head(Adj.Close, 1) < tail(Adj.Close, 1)) "GREEN" else "RED"
)
```